# Accidentally formatted the partition which contained ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, system-installation

While installing windows 7, I accidentally did that. But, I have the backups of,

```
/var (except /var/run, /var/cache, /var/tmp)
/srv
/etc
/root
/home
/usr (/usr/local only, nothing else)
```

what is the best way to make sure that I get back the system as it was?

Comment: What did the system have on it, how long have you been using it and how many programs have you installed not from the official repositories?

Comment: Did you do anything other than delete partition? You may be able to restore with testdisk? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step  I like to have a backup of installed applications using dpkg, to make it easy to add all applications back in. I just then do a new install, restore /home, and restore all apps. If totally custom settings in /etc I might restore manual just those few files. Like my 40_custom in grub.

Comment: It had ROS, a lot many python modules, 3 different versions of python. I have been using it past 1 year, I haven't count of it but I guess I had google chrome, etc

Comment: @oldfred No, just the deletion of the partition

Comment: So you deleted the partition with the Windows 7 setup disc but not begin installing Windows?  In that case the recommendation of TestDisc may be a good one, although I do believe when deleting a partition Windows often wipes the first few sectors, which would make recovery more compex.

Answer (score 0):

I would:

- run a fresh installation (and perhaps even use the opportunity to upgrade to 16.04 LTS)
- restore /usr/local , /home and /srv. This assumes your user ID remains 1000.
- run a diff between the fresh /etc and the back up of /etc and that will tell you what other packages you need to install and what special configuration changes you need to do.